# git submodule not fetched by repo checkout

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm a git newbie. My git repo includes submodule references. I have a post-receive hook to checkout the repo contents to my web directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/www/hello_world_php git checkout -f
```

(Per this [blog post](http://goo.gl/Ybzik).)

It works fine except that the submodule directories in the www directory are NOT populated.

How to fix?

Comment: Have you cloned the submodules yet?

    `git clone --recursive <super_project>`

or if you've already cloned the super project

    `git submodule update`

Comment: I've now tried to clone as you suggest. But git complained since the dir had been filled when I did the submodule add. So I've given up on submodules and just did the clone. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

For a cloned repo, what I do when I see I don't have anything in `.git/modules/xxx`, is:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

See [my script for an example](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitlab/install_or_update_gitlab.sh.tpl#L23-L28).

If you don't, all you have is an empty directory representing your submodule root, and stored in your working tree as a [special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309) (mode 160000).