# Does git change submodule reference when switching branch

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-submodules

here is the situation i faced.
I have a repo containing a submodule. In the repo, i created a new branch to do some editing.

Then i found out i need an updated submodule, so i pulled down the submodule and kept working. 
I made a commit afterward, and merge the branch back to the master branch.

In the master branch, when i use "git submodule update", the submodule points back to an old version, but not to the updated one in the branch :(

I am wondering if git merges submodules reference? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

In your branch, after pulling the submodule '`xxx`', you need to go back in the parent repo (in the folder which contains your submodule) and do a:

```
git add xxx
git commit -m "Updated submodule"
```

That will record an updated [special entry of the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309) memorizing the new SHA1 for submodule '`xxx`'.

That is that special entry which needs to be updated when you merge your branch back to `master`.

If you forget the `git add/git commit` step in the branch, the merge back to `master` would keep the special entry unchanged, still referring to the old SHA1.

Comment: I added the bounty because I have the same problem as OP - however I *have* added and committed the submodule in the original branch. It doesn't show up in the branch I merged into.

Comment: @SteveFallows "it doesn't show up" meaning "the submodule doesn't show up"? Or the submodule is there, but its updated content with the pulled SHA1 doesn't show up?

Comment: The latter - It is still the SHA1 of the original version, not the updated version that I committed in the other branch, before merging. There are other submodules in the project where this has been done OK - not sure what I fouled up here.

Comment: @SteveFallows Maybe this module was modified in both branches? As opposed to the other correctly updated submodules, which were modified only in the `dev` branch, before being merged back to `master`?

Comment: @SteveFallows Or that particular submodule has somehow lost its submodule status (check the `.gitmodules` file, and the `.git/modules` folder). A `git submodule update --init` might be in order.

Comment: Thanks, but it's neither of those. I've run git submodule update -- init many times while working on this. I've punted for now and directly updated the second branch. I'll see what happens on next merge.

Comment: 4 years later I can confirm I'm having the same problem.  On my work branch, I updated a submodule from version A to version B. `git status` showed `modified: [submodule name] (new commits)`.  I used `git add [submodule name]` and `git commit` to commit this update to the work branch.  Then I checked out master, and merged the work branch into master.  I expected the master would now reference version B of the submodule, but `git submodule update` changed it back to version A.  I had to add and commit the submodule update on the master branch, separately to the work branch.