# "nothing to commit (working directory clean)" when a folder has been added

Tags: linux, git, github

I have a problem in git. I don't know why it says "nothing to commit (working directory clean)."

My development env: CentOS 6.4

My process is below:

1. `mkdir develop`
2. `cd develop`
3. `git init(set user.name, user.email)`
4. `git remote add origin "repository_name"`
5. `git clone "repository_name"`
6. Add "Test" folder
   **(amon2-setup.pl --flavor=Basic Test)**
7. `git status` -> at this point, i can see "Untracked files ~~ Test/"
8. `cd "Test"` folder
9. `git status` -> at this point, nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Why does it say this? And if i pushed "Test", my github pushed data has been "subproject," so, i can't see Test folder's contents. Why is that?

Linux(bad)
http://www.fastpic.jp/viewer.php?file=6541584337.png

add amon files from Linux(bad i can't open files)
http://www.fastpic.jp/viewer.php?file=4456741517.png

Windows(ok)
http://www.fastpic.jp/images.php?file=8061488422.png

add amon files from Windows(ok)
http://www.fastpic.jp/viewer.php?file=8164112210.png

Comment: What does the line `but moved to "Test" folder` mean?

Comment: Is there anything in the folder? Git doesn't track empty directories.

Comment: >>David sorry, cd Test/

Comment: >> duskwuff yes. do you know Amon2? I did amon2 setup Test, there are Amon2 default data in Test folder

Comment: I'm not seeing any "git add" commands. If you don't add them they aren't tracked.

Comment: What is the `git clone` (step 5) line for?

Comment: What is the version of git, both on Windows and on Unix?

Answer (score 1):

The gray folder for Test means:

[image: http://www.fastpic.jp/images.php?file=4456741517.png]

Test is added as a **submodule**, which is why git status in the parent repo reports that "Test" must be added (it is a [`special entry`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992018/git-submodule-update-needed-only-initially/2227598#2227598) in the index of the parent repo, which record that submodule)

Once in `Test` (which is a nested git repo), since that repo has no file, the git status reports a clear index.

Note also that Windows isn't case sensitive, so '`Test`' wouldn't register properly, if there is already a '`test`' (lowercase)

Comment: thanks VonC. but why submodule... i did do git remote add git@~~ i didn't type commands contains "submodule".

Comment: You didn't, but either your repo already contain a submodule, or the Amon2 setup process creates one. In any case, avoid having a `test` and a `Test` with different case. On Windows, this will lead to trouble.