# What is this grey git icon?

Tags: github

Looks like a folder inside of a folder - or maybe a lock? The file cannot be opened and none of the content appears to be there.

One thing I do know is that this folder is a repo itself, inside of a repo

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a grey icon in remote GitHub mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering it is [a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19131821/6309), one way for you to see its content is to:

- clone that gitHub repo locally
- do a:

  ```
  git submodule update --init
  ```

But you should be able to click on it and browse its content directly from the web, if it was a repo hosted by GitHub.
See an example in my project https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything, where the submodule [SemanticUI](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI) is directly browsable.

Comment: i did the same thing; did a `git init` by mistake in a sub folder. this fix worked for me

Answer (score 0):

That is the github icon for a git [submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).
From the book: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules