# Can't stage folder for commit with git add . or git add -u

Tags: git, github, staging

so if I do a git status I get:

```
bsg-integration> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   bsg-services (untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I then tried using `git add .` and `git add -u` but I still get the same thing when i use `git status`. What is going on and how to I push this folder to github? On my github repo the folder bsg-services is showing up as a greyed out folder. What does this mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It (`bsg-services`) is a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**. (see "[What is this grey git icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20418179/6309)")

You need to:

- add/commit by going in that folder first (and push from that sub repo),
  (a git status inside `bsg-services` will tell you more)
- then go back to the parent repo (where you are), add, commit and push.
  The commit you will have done inside `bsg-services` will have modified the **[gitlink entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** in the index of your parent repo.

So you need both pushes:

- one from the submodule repo to its upstream repo (a `git remote -v` should show you that)
- one from the parent repo in order to record the new gitlink SHA1 which memorizes the new state of that submodule.

Comment: Note: to remove a submodule: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/21381862/6309

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem.

Goto **bsg-services** subdirectory and make a commit. Thats It!

What happened was you had another git repository inside the **bsg-services** directory. If u need to get rid of that remove .git directory from **bsg-services** sub-directory.