# "Git add ." can not stage files in subfolder

Tags: git

I am just starting to learn git commands and came across a strange issue. 
On my local mac, I have a repo in directory "1st-repo" with only 2 things: (1)"README.md" (2)"myFolder" subfolder containing a bunch of files

To stage all my files at once, I entered directory "`1st-repo`" and ran command "`git add .`" like shown below:

[image: git add]

However, after this, when I run `git status`, it still shows `myFolder` not staged.
Can someone help me figure out why?

[image: git status]

Comment: Unable to access your screenshots. Make sure myFolder is not listed in .gitignore file

Comment: This will probably solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167676/cant-stage-folder-for-commit-with-git-add-or-git-add-u

Comment: In general, if you can possibly paste text from the terminal instead of sharing pictures of text, it's really much much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if `myFolder/` includes itself a `.git/` subfolder.

That would make it a nested Git repository inside `1st-repo`.

If you don't need that nested repository in `myFolder/`, move/remove `myFolder/.git`, and try your git add . again from `1st-repo`.