# VSCode doesn't commit modified folder, how to fix this?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, commit

In VScode I've made some changes and then tried to commit them, all files' have been committed without an issue except for the **folder** itself.
You can see below it shows jamming folder M (modified) but when I tried to commit or stage it doesn't do anything. Can anyone help?
[image]

Adding the message showing up when typed `git status`
[image]

And here is the OUTPUT when I tried to commit:

```
Looking for git in: /usr/bin/git
Using git 2.20.1 (Apple Git-117) from /usr/bin/git
> git rev-parse --show-toplevel
> git rev-parse --git-dir
Open repository: /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git show :jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git show :jamming/src/components/App/App.js
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/components/App/App.js
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git show :jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git log --format=%H%n%aN%n%aE%n%at%n%ct%n%P%n%B -z -n21 -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git log --format=%H%n%aN%n%aE%n%at%n%ct%n%P%n%B -z -n41 -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git add -A -- .
> git commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
> git config --get-all user.name
> git config --get-all user.email
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git show :jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
git.stage 1
git.stage.scmResources 1
> git add -A -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git add -A -- .
> git commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
> git config --get-all user.name
> git config --get-all user.email
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git show :jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git add -A -- .
> git commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
> git config --get-all user.name
> git config --get-all user.email
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git show :jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git rev-list --count 7b2cd1f8ccaa51ff4c5fcc150e51238d06a07dcc.. -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git log --format=%H%n%aN%n%aE%n%at%n%ct%n%P%n%B -z -n3 -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git show :jamming/src/util/deneme
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/deneme
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git show :deneme
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/deneme
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git show :jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git show :deneme
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/deneme
> git show :jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git show :deneme
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/deneme
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git show :deneme.js
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/deneme.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git show :jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git show :deneme.js
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/deneme.js
> git show :jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git log --format=%H%n%aN%n%aE%n%at%n%ct%n%P%n%B -z -n21 -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
git.stage 1
git.stage.scmResources 1
> git add -A -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
git.stage 1
git.stage.scmResources 1
> git add -A -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git add -A -- .
> git commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
> git config --get-all user.name
> git config --get-all user.email
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git show :jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git rev-list --count 7b2cd1f8ccaa51ff4c5fcc150e51238d06a07dcc.. -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git rev-list --count 7b2cd1f8ccaa51ff4c5fcc150e51238d06a07dcc.. -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git log --format=%H%n%aN%n%aE%n%at%n%ct%n%P%n%B -z -n3 -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git log --format=%H%n%aN%n%aE%n%at%n%ct%n%P%n%B -z -n3 -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git ls-files --stage -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git show :jamming/src/util/Spotify.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
git.stage 1
git.stage.scmResources 1
> git add -A -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
git.stage 1
git.stage.scmResources 1
> git add -A -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
git.stage 1
git.stage.scmResources 1
> git add -A -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
git.stage 1
git.stage.scmResources 1
> git add -A -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
git.stage 1
git.stage.scmResources 1
> git add -A -- /Users/basakulcay/Desktop/Web_Development/Codeacademy/jamming/jamming
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
```

Comment: What does `git status` say, when you type it into a terminal?

Comment: Just added above @Coli, thank you for looking into.

Comment: Okay and what does `git diff jamming` say?

Comment: did you try `git add .` in the vscode terminal and commit?

Comment: @Coli it says the following : diff --git a/jamming b/jamming
--- a/jamming
+++ b/jamming
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 84a17b968fb6959968416012af412a488964ca45
+Subproject commit 84a17b968fb6959968416012af412a488964ca45-dirty

Comment: I did, still no luck @tHeSiD

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167676/cant-stage-folder-for-commit-with-git-add-or-git-add-u is this similar to your problem?

Comment: @tHeSiD kind of, but i'm not sure what tthat means since I am already in the jamming folder: add/commit by going in that folder first (and push from that sub repo),
(a git status inside bsg-services will tell you more)

Comment: was this folder itself a git repository before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907159/unable-to-add-folder-to-git-repo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215759/discussion-between-basak-ulcay-and-thesid).