# git not adding files from different git directory

Tags: git, git-submodules, revision

How do you add git revisioned files to a different git?

Current Setup:

```
env/A.txt
env/.git         <-- parent git

env/docs
env/docs/B.txt
env/docs/.git    <-- child git
```

While inside `env` directory I want to be able to add all files to parent git including the ones from child git. For some reason I am not able to do that. All files that are inside `env/docs/B.txt` are not adding to parent git. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason I am not able to do that

That is expected: docs is considered a nested Git repository, and only its root tree SHA1 would be recorded, as a gitlink.
It is *not* a submodule, not unless you have a `.gitmodules` at the root of your parent repo, referencing `docs/`.

You would need first to remove the gitlink if you already added it: see "[Nested GIT Repository mistake method to remove it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25093098/6309)"

Then one solution is to add the `docs` remote repo as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.
But if you don't care about the history of those files, the other approach would be to move or remove the `docs/.git` folder: that would make `docs/` a regular subfolder, that you can add and commits from its parent folder `envs/`.