# Unable to open 'client (Working Tree)': Unable to read file

Tags: git, github

I have an issue with my git repository. When adding changes to my client app, git seems to get confused about which files were changed. See image below:

[image]

When trying to commit the changes I get this error message:

[image]

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem recently, and it was caused by having a separate .git in the Client sub-directory. I deleted it and it was fixed.

Comment: HOWEVER, you will also need to execute `git rm --cached <sub-directoryName>` so that the parent repo will know to start tracking the files/folders that were previously tracked by the sub-directory's git "submodule".
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25093098/9974771

Answer (score 0):

I actually faced that problem not so long ago. If this happens, try to locate your main client folder and delete it. Try adding it again then, and it should work. At least this worked for me.