# Why can I not open my folder in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

The "src" folder in [one of my repository](https://github.com/anwarab96/CoreJava) is grayed out (and is not clickable):

[image: screenshot]

I took the following steps before pushing to the GitHub:

1. I created a new repository on GitHub.
2. I initialize dthe git on my project.
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -m "comment"`
5. `git remote add origin url`
6. `git push -u origin master`
7. username
8. password

The "src" folder is showing up on GitHub but cannot be opened. What can I do?

Comment: Can you share a link to the relevant project?

Comment: If the last commit resulted in error, this might sometimes be the case.

Comment: There is only a single commit on github, are you sure you are on the master branch locally?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a grey icon in remote GitHub mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean)

Answer (score 51):

I solved the problem by ***deleting .git folder*** inside subfolders (Hidden files and folders). You should have only one ***.git*** in the root folder.

Git recognized that folder as *`modified but untracked content`*. 
There are other solutions for this problem, look this thread: [Git - how to track untracked content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4161022/2884309)

Comment: I'd like to note that (somehow) I couldn't open folder A because folder B (which is in the same folder as A) had a `.git`

Comment: I removed the folder, but it didn't fix the problem

Comment: Git doesn't say the folder is untracked, but it cannot be opened in github.

Answer (score 29):

There are two possible reasons to this

1. You have a git folder within a git folder i.e. your src folder is a git folder itself. To fix that simply delete the .git folder within the src and

```
git add <foldername>
```

```
git commit -m "commit msg"
```

```
git push origin master
```

Incase if it still doesn't get fixed then, there maybe the problem because of cache. To fix that simple type

```
git rm --cached <foldername>
```

and repeat the above steps again. Your problem should get fixed.

Comment: git rm --cached <foldername>   . This command alone helped me to get what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 22):

After you added a local folder:

1. Remove `.git` folder **inside of untracked submodule**.

- Powershell: `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force .\.git\`
- Linux Terminal: `rm -rf ./.git`

2. Run `git rm --cached . -rf` inside the submodule, which was the key for me.
3. `git add .` in parent or root folder and you are good to go.

Answer (score 11):

The icon mean that you have marked this folder as **[`submodule`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)**.
open your .gitmodules and you will see there the  folder named as src  bin.

Remove them from your **[`submodule`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)** and it will become a regular folder

[What is this grey git icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412396/what-is-this-grey-git-icon)

Answer (score 7):

I tried everything from above and nothing seemed to work in my case so I just renamed the trouble folder in something else then Github recognized it for some reason when I pushed the changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you clone the project you will find, that these folders are in fact empty:

```
​$ ls -la bin
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 fabiopoloni  staff   68  8 Okt 12:18 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 8 fabiopoloni  staff  272  8 Okt 12:18 ..

​$ ls -la src
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 fabiopoloni  staff   68  8 Okt 12:18 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 8 fabiopoloni  staff  272  8 Okt 12:18 ..
```

There is also no `.gitmodules` so it'll show you an error when viewing the status / syncing it:

```
​$ git submodule status
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'bin'

​$ git submodule sync
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'bin'
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'src'
```

Since they're empty, the easiest way is to delete them and commit:

```
​$ rm -rf bin
​$ rm -rf src
​$ git commit -a -m 'Removed empty submodules folders'
$ git push
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue.

The command I gave was :

```
git add <foldername>
```

The problem here is we forgot to mention that we need this as a folder :

```
git add <foldername>/
```

With the backslash , we can now see that all the files of this folder are getting displayed and this works for me!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you initialize a repository in the child directories.
For me, I'd initialized a git repo inside the client directory.
In your case it might be the src directory, try `rm -rf .git` inside the src directory, this would delete the `.git` file inside the `src` directory, and try pushing the changes again `src` would be available then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my react folder but I had solved it by
.
.
git rm --cached

Answer (score 0):

Despite deleting the .git folder github did not add properly the affected folder. I did not want to delete the folder and I instead did the following:

I've solved it with the following order

In my example let's say that I've the following repo structure

```
app
| - .git # <- Correct .git of the repo
| - dir1
| - dir2
| - subApp
| ---
    | - .git # <- Mistake here because there was another .git
    | - subfolder1
    | - ....
| - dir 3
```

Now with the followig structure and git with not allow you to push the content of the `subfolder` because it contains already a `.git` (in my case it was created by an automatic process)

#### Solution

1. Remove the `.git` folder

```
rm -rf ./subApp/.git
```

2. Rename `subApp` and push changes

```
rm subApp subAppTemp
```

3. Add and push

```
git add subAppTemp
git commit -m "Temporary push"
git push
```

4. Rename it to original name and push back to git

```
rm subAppTemp subApp
git add subApp
git commit -m "Correct push of dir.."
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.git` folder from client.