# Creating new git repository, can't add directory

Tags: github

I am about to throw my laptop through a wall, and am hoping for help before reaching that point. For reference, I am following these instructions exactly - https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/.

I have a directory ".../path/thisdir". Inside of thisdir are (1) a file called Demo.R and (2) a directory called sportVU. sportVU is a directory with ~15 files in it.

When I follow the instructions in that link, my github repo looks like this:

https://github.com/NicholasCanova/packageSportVU

Notice that the sportVU directory link cannot be clicked in github, and when I download the repo, sportVU is an empty folder. Why is this happening? This shouldn't be so tough.

EDIT: this is what the repo looks like in my local machine, I'm 100% sure it's not empty:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you have two .git folder in your directory. View hidden folders to see.

Similar questions:
[What does a grey icon in remote GitHub mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean)

[Why can I not open my folder in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384464/why-can-i-not-open-my-folder-in-github)

Comment: how do i view hidden folders?

Comment: Using Terminal, navigate to that directory and use the command `ls -a`

Comment: I think I found the issue - Pathspec 'file' is in submodule 'sportVU'

Comment: so it appears that all of the files in the sportVU directory are not able to be added for this reason?

Comment: Try removing all .git and git related folders ( using command line `rm -rf <directory>`), and then start the `git init` process again.

Answer (score 0):

Since Git doesn't store empty folders the steps you should follow exactly are:

Delete the old repo and start again following exactly my steps.

1. `git clone <repo url>`
2. Inside the folder of the cloned repo create a directory manually and name it as you want i.e sportVU.
3. Drag and Drop all the files you want in the sportVU direcrory.
4. cd to Myrepo/sportVU and type `git add *`
5. type `git commit -m "added some files"`
6. git push -u origin master.

and you should be all set

Comment: I've done this and it hasn't helped. it would appear Alon is onto something above, I'm looking into his links now