# Why can I not open my folder in GitHub?

Tags: github

Why can I not open my folder in GitHub? It has already been asked but i could not find the right solution for me. Here is the link for the same problem: [Why can I not open my folder in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384464/why-can-i-not-open-my-folder-in-github). Can anyone help me to get rid of it. Thanks in advance

Comment: To say the least we're going to need some more information.

Comment: @jhpratt here is the link for my github repo https://github.com/karanpepi/mean-stack-crud. Do let me know if anything more is required

Answer (score 1):

That is because ngApp is itself a git repo (that folder included a .git subfolder in it)

So when you `git add .` in your repo, it just recorded ngApp as a **gitlink** (a SHA1 reference to the repo) without any URL (as opposed to a submodule, where a `.gitmodules` would include the url of the remote repo).
When you clone your repo back, that is all you get: a reference without URL.

If [`karanpepi/mean-stack-crud`](https://github.com/karanpepi/mean-stack-crud) is supposed to include `ngApp` folder, go back to your local repo (where you have the `ngApp` folder) and delete the `.git`

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git rm ngApp
git commit -m "remove gitlink"
rm -Rf ngApp/.git
git add ngApp
git commit -m "Add ngApp content"
git push
```

Comment: so how can i resolve it. Sorry  i am new to github any help would be appreciated. @Vonc

Comment: @Karan I have included the steps to resolve the situation.

Comment: Thanks it worked. rm -Rf ngApp/.git this was the key for my lock. @VonC