# Pushed Github folder is not clickable and shows as below

Tags: github, mern

[image: GITHUB]

Below steps i followed,

```
Git init
git add .
git commit -m "First Commit"
git push origin master
```

what am I doing wrong to resolve the problem?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384464/why-can-i-not-open-my-folder-in-github/33012796

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is there anything special about that folder in your local file system?

Comment: That folder contains React project in it. I could not open that folder in the github whereas i can able to open backend folder. Frontend folder has sub folders like src, public etc whereas backend folder doesn't have sub folders in it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the frontend folder and get rid of the .git file since you have another.git file in the root folder.