# I am trying to access my project folder in git but not opening

Tags: git, github

[image: Screenshot]

This three folders are not accessing

1. HibernatewithspringBoot
2. RestfullWebApp
3. WebApp

only SpringBootWithHibernate is opening

Comment: Are you talking about Git or Github? Those icons are not normal folder icons. Perhaps they're symlinks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub folders have a white arrow on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them)

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting **.git** folder in any of the subfolders. Refer to the below answer for more details : 
 [Why can I not open my folder in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384464/why-can-i-not-open-my-folder-in-github)