# Greyed out folder in GitHub repo?

Tags: github

Hey so I pushed a new folder to my GitHub repository and well it is greyed out. Why?

I'm new to git and have probably done something to git to cause this so how can i start from fresh?

Here's a link to my repo: https://github.com/ZoidinCode/ZoidinCode.github.io/tree/master/dist

I've uninstalled Git and then re-installed it and well this has happened :(

Git:

```
  cd desktop/Artificial-Reason-1.4.6
bash: cd: desktop/Artificial-Reason-1.4.6: No such file or directory

XXXX~/desktop/Artificial-Reason-1.4.6 (master)
$ git add dist/header_light_dark

XXXX ~/desktop/Artificial-Reason-1.4.6 (master)
$ git commit -m "First commit to GitHub"
[master 0e2035b] First commit to GitHub
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 160000 dist/header_light_dark

XXXX ~/desktop/Artificial-Reason-1.4.6 (master)
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 1229, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1223/1223), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1229/1229), 49.79 MiB | 443.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1229 (delta 848), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/ZoidinCode/ZoidinCode.github.io.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a grey icon in remote GitHub mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean)

Comment: Still stuck as my git is acting funny and i can't do anything, Any help? @Chris

Comment: "Acting funny" isn't a very useful description. Can you elaborate? Did the answers in the duplicate question help?

Answer (score 9):

A gray folder on GitHub looks like a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, as I mentioned in:

- "[What is this grey git icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20412396/6309)"
- "[What does a grey icon in remote GitHub mean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19584255/6309)"

It is not a sub-folder, but a [special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309) in [the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309) which marks it as a submodule-like.

If you don't have a `.gitmodules` file in your main repo, that special entry is typical of adding a **nested repo**: check if your `dist/` folder has itself a `.git/` subfolder.

To fix the issue, try a `git rm --cached dist` (no trailing slash).
See more at "[Cannot remove submodule from Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21381862/6309)"

```
git rm --cached dist
git commit -m "Remove submodule entry"
rm -Rf dist/.git # delete the nested repo
git add dist
git commit -m "Add dist plain subfolder"
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have initialised git inside this folder. To fix change directory into this folder and delete `.git` then `add` `commit` and `push` again.