# Jitpack doent build project

Tags: android, maven, github, gradle, jitpack

I have been trying for a week. but it does not work. Jitpack does not build my GitHub project.
I do not know what to do.

Here my log:
https://jitpack.io/com/github/ludev-studio/colorpicker-android/1.0.3/build.log

And my git repo:
https://github.com/LuDev-Studio/colorpicker-android/tree/1.0.3

How can i build that repo?

Answer (score 0):

Your [`GitHub repo`](https://github.com/LuDev-Studio/colorpicker-android/tree/1.0.3) includes a gray folder `colorpicker`, which means you must have a nested Git repo: locally, your `colorpicker` folder must include a `.git/` subdirectory in it.

See [my answer to "Greyed out folder in GitHub repo?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34478522/6309) in order for you to reference your actual files.
As long as you do not upload those files, kitpack won't see it when it checks out your repo.