# Git extension - What is Grey icon?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I use git replace to truncate the git history.

$ git replace 4c9f81eb5b7a331d1d0f8edcac24e8a69fdd3353 70b8267e3a67ddb4ba56ff92
7dc3871f8a96d1e2

However git create new strange commit with grey color as follow:

[image: Strange icon]

What is it? How to remove it completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is replace refs

- git replace -l will show all replace refs
- git replace -d ref-hash
  will remove the replace refs

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a sub-module of your existing repo has been created, learn more about it from the given bellow link.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

More stack overflow references in bellow threads:

1. [What does a grey icon in remote GitHub mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean)
2. [What is this grey git icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412396/what-is-this-grey-git-icon)

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't submodule. Submodules-> Manage Submodules doesn't show any submodule