# Git submodule's commit matching a tag in the main repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

After I check out a tag and do `git status`, it shows me:

```
#       modified:   submodules/bcg729 (new commits)
#       modified:   submodules/belle-sip (new commits)
#       modified:   submodules/externals/ffmpeg (new commits)
```

`git submodule update` checks out earlier commits.
But in `.gitmodules` there's no info about specific commits in submodules when the tag was created. How does git knows it? Simply by the commit dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No those commits are registered as a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309).

Try a `git ls-files --stage`, and look for entry in mode "160000":

```
git ls-files --stage | grep 160000
```

You will see the SHA1 associated for each submodules in the `grep` result.

The `.gitmodules` is only there to record the name and url of the submodule, not its SHA1.