# How to update git submodule who's history was rewritten

Tags: git, rebase

Say I have a git submodule already setup, and the upstream commit history has rewritten (for example a rebase squash was preformed).

Say the commit my submodule head is set to no longer exits. So I want to set the head hash submodule's repo's head. How do I do that?

Comment: Just as a note, the commit your submodule's head was set to does still exist. If you want to prevent it being garbage-collected (after ninety days or so) you can add your own reference to it with a tag or `merge -s ours`ing it into a `preserved-history` branch or however you want to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply go in the submodule, do a git fetch, and checkout the HEAD you need.

```
cd mysubmodule
git fetch
git checkout origin/abranch
```

Then you go back to the parent repo, add and commit that [new submodule SHA1 entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309).

Note that you also can [convert a submodule in order to follow the latest commits of a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309).
In that case, a simple:

```
git submodule update --remote
```

would be enough.