# How can a commit in git submodule trigger a build in continuous integration？

Tags: git, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm working on project A, and A is depending on a fast-developing project B(its master branch).

Therefore, B is a submodule of A, everytime I build A, B is also re-built. Besides, everytime B has a new commit, I need to build B, then re-built A.(Luckily, the projects are small enough, so the compiling time isn't important).

Now, here's the point. I want to trigger a new build in Travis CI or other continuous integration services, when there is a new commit in project A or B.

I just tried Github & Travis CI. A commit in project B would not trigger a build in project A. Is there a simple way to run such a continuous integration?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. Normally with submodules, your main project would depend on _a particular revision_ of the submodule. An update in the submodule repo _shouldn't_ trigger a build in the primary repo until the primary repo's dependency is updated to a newer revision, which would cause a rebuild of the main repo anyway. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Chris thanks. I know it's better to depend on a revision. But in this case, project B is developing really fast, leaving no revision for me to depend, and I need to keep the pace with master branch. This situation is not common, but really exists.

Comment: So you have a submodule tracking a branch (i.e. created using the `-b` flag) and you want to kick off a new build for the primary repository any time the submodule branch is updated?

Comment: @Chris yes, that's what I want. Sorry for my expression

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> A commit in project B would not trigger a build in project A

That is expected, considering B has no idea A exists.

You would need to record the new state of B (new **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309)) of project A by doing:

```
cd /path/to/projectA
git submodule update --remote
git add .
git commit -m "Record new B SHA1 gitlink"
git push
```

`git submodule update --remote` will update submodule B to the latest commit of the branch recorded in A `.gitmodules` file for B.
See "[git submodule tracking latest](http://Git%20submodules:%20Specify%20a%20branch/tag)" and "[Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)"

Then a new Travis build would be triggered for A.

If you want to automate the sequence described above, you would need a [webhook (GitHub)](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) ([or BitBucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html)) for projectB, and a local listener which, on a push event on repo B, would trigger the commands mentioned before in a local repo of project A.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @VonC 's question, I solved this problem.
Ref https://developer.github.com/webhooks/configuring/

1. I set up project Monitor, which has two submodules, project A and B
2. Create file `trigger.rb` in project Monitor

require 'sinatra'

```
post '/payload' do
  system("git submodule update --remote")
  system("git add .")
  system("git commit -m Record_new_change")
  system("git push")
  puts "Finished handling"
end
```

3. [Download ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download), run it on a VPS or a long running commpuer with `./ngrok http 4567`. You may got a link like `http://7e9ea9dc.ngrok.io`
4. Run `ruby trigger.rb`
5. Fork project B to B', write another script to make sure that all the commits are synchronized to project B'
6. Go to project settings page, create a new webhook, whose url is `http://7e9ea9dc.ngrok.io/payload` for project A and B'
7. Add project Monitor to Travis CI

In this way, the development for A and B is untouched, and the new builds can be triggered automatically.

Comment: Looks nice (in addition to my answer)! +1

Answer (score 1):

I have used gitlab-ci to trigger a parent pipeline when a submodule is updated. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68870892/14417051)