# Old submodule leads to error in tree (tree contains duplicate file entries)

Tags: git

I am trying to migrate a repository from Bitbucket to GitHub which fails due to an error in the tree.

`git fsck` gives the following output:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
warning in tree 86b6f36a93c983faab565674a0b92f93fb22cfc7: nullSha1: contains entries pointing to null sha1
error in tree 86b6f36a93c983faab565674a0b92f93fb22cfc7: duplicateEntries: contains duplicate file entries
```

Checking the malicious tree hash with `git ls-tree 86b6f36a93c983faab565674a0b92f93fb22cfc7`

Gives me--among others--these lines:

```
160000 commit 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  foobar
040000 tree 2abdf38e2288bca8be24df800372c6a96ecef111    foobar
```

I know that the first line [stands for a deleted sub module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992018/git-submodule-update-needed-only-initially/2227598#2227598). I would like to remove the reference to this from the history to allow me to push this to GitHub.