# Git Submodule inside a folder with folders and files to be ignored

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have encountered a situation that a git submodule is inside a folder which containing other folders that to be ignored. The structure is like the following:

```
lib/
  submodule-folder/
  other-folder/       # This is folder should be ignored
```

My question is that can I just add `lib/` to `.gitignore` to achieve the goal of `other-folder` being ignored while the submodule still working as normal? Or should I exclude the submodule pattern in `.gitignore` such as

```
lib/*
!lib/submodule-folder/
```

I have tried the first way and the submodule seems to work well when using command like `git submodule update`, but is still not sure if this is correct since I cannot find reference for explaining that. Does anyone run into a situation like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the submodule is already tracked (meaning its root folder `lib/submodule-folder/` is already part of the Git history as **[a gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309)**), then yes, you can add `lib/` to a `.gitignore`.

That will ignore everything *else* within the `lib/` folder.

To double-check the submodule folder is *not* ignored by any `.gitignore` rule, check that the following command does return nothing:

```
git check-ignore -v -- lib/submodule-folder
```

(no trailing slash in this instance)

Comment: Many thanks on your comment! This indeed give me much help